# How does near protocol distinguish between contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

https://examples.near.org/rust-status-message

You can deploy your smart contract using:

```
near deploy --wasmFile res/status_message.wasm --accountId YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

And we are calling the contract function set_status using:

```
near call YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME set_status '{"message": "aloha friend"}' --accountId YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

The function is here:

```
#[near_bindgen]
impl StatusMessage {
    pub fn set_status(&mut self, message: String) {
        env::log(b"A");
        let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
        self.records.insert(&account_id, &message);
    }

    pub fn get_status(&self, account_id: String) -> Option<String> {
        env::log(b"A");
        return self.records.get(&account_id);
    }
}
```

How does near protocol distinguish between contract?

What if some other contracts have set_status function, which contract function it will call. Also what if I redeploy the contract and run the function. Which contract function will it call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you need to know that will hopefully clear this up:

- Every contract deployed to NEAR **must consume 1 account.**
- Every account on NEAR **must have 0 or 1 contract**.
- Account names follow a pattern lik DNS with network as top level

  - `your-account.testnet` could be your main developer account on TestNet
  - `contract-v1.your-account.testnet` could be v1 of a contract you wrote
  - `your-token.your-account.testnet` could be a [fungible token](https://github.com/nearprotocol/NEPs/blob/master/specs/Standards/Tokens/FungibleToken.md) that you control

When working with our examples, the deployment process uses the `near dev-deploy` command which does 4 things in 2 steps (see attached image from [NEAR Explorer](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/))

**step 1** (batch transaction)

- 1.1. create new account (**`your-account`**)
- 1.2. fund the account from faucet with 100 NEAR
- 1.3. add `FullAccess` key to that account

**step 2**

- 2.1 deploy the contract (**`path/to.wasm`**) to the new account (**`your-account`**)

[image: NEAR Explorer contract deployment transactions]

The deploy command you included above

> ```
> near deploy --wasmFile path/to.wasm --accountId YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
> ```

only does the last step, **2.1**.

For the first 3 things in step 1 (**1.1** - **1.3**) you will need this:

```
near create_account a-contract-on.your-account.testnet --master-account your-account.testnet --helper-url https://helper.testnet.near.org
```

where `your-account.testnet` was created beforehand using [NEAR Wallet](https://wallet.testnet.near.org)

You can see these links for more details:

- [Accounts on NEAR](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account)
- [Fundamentals of NEAR Protocol](https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-near-apis#fundamentals-of-near-protocol)

Comment: The documentation says contracts are upgradable. "Subsequent deployments overwrite contract code without affecting storage (except for the STATE key which holds the contract code)"  Then how it can remain decentralized, as the contract code will remain in the control of contract deployer.

Comment: There seems  Limited access for the account like multi-sig and lockup contract.

Comment: For a contract to be trustless, the owner usually need to delete all full access keys and sometimes all access keys.

Comment: And how to delete the full access keys?

Comment: `near delete-key <account-id> <access-key>` see: https://docs.near.org/docs/development/near-cli#near-delete-key